# Openshift occasionally shuts down all my gears (including cron 1.4) and doesn't bring it back

Tags: cron, openshift, gears

I added a cron gear with the whole purpose of running a script that can detect when my app goes down (jboss + haproxy). So far from I can tell, openshift just takes the gears down but doesn't bring them back up.  There are no memory violations of any kind and the app uses a tiny fraction of the 1G allowed.

It appears that openshift shuts down ALL the gears including cron so I am back to square one.  Is there a way to make sure my app is always up or can be restarted if needed? I could always monitor it from the outside the openshift environment but wondering if there is a better way.  Thanks

Comment: Are you using a Free plan or a Bronze plan?

Comment: We are using a Bronze plan

Comment: What you are describing can happen occasionally when they are performing maintenance. It shouldn't happen often though. Have you inspected all your server logs to make sure your application isn't crashing for some reason?

Comment: My app is not crashing and even if the jboss server for some reason died, it shouldn't stop the cron gear.  If it did, that would be an architecture flaw.   I just wonder what people do in production environments. Does openshift expect everyone to monitor things from outside and use rhc to restart things? Is this a known bug they are trying to fix? Any ideas? Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: You should probably open a support ticket with OpenShift